# How to select an exact string in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to select a string with an exact value of "RM" in my XML document.

Here is a sample of my document. Note that the structure and values of other nodes are not permanent, so I cannot use a relative location to aid me.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLT.xsl"?>
<document xmlns="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <page ocr-vers="OmniPageCSDK18" app-vers="OmniPage 19">
        <description>
            <source file="C:\Users\User\Documents\OCR\Unprocessed\7740412639.pdf" dpix="300" dpiy="300" sizex="2480" sizey="3509"/>
            <theoreticalPage size="A4" marginLeft="1440" marginTop="0" marginRight="1440" marginBottom="1440" offsetX="-2" offsetY="-2" width="11918" height="16854"/>
        </description>
        <body>
            <dd l="87" t="322" r="9667" b="16536">
                <dd l="115" t="322" r="9667" b="16536">
                    <picture l="115" t="322" r="9667" b="16536" alignment="left">
                    </picture>
                </dd>
                <dd l="7205" t="1166" r="7366" b="1392">
                    <para l="7234" t="1171" r="7334" b="1392" alignment="left" spaceBefore="29" spaceAfter="24" lsp="exactly" lspExact="100" language="en">
                        <ln l="7234" t="1171" r="7334" b="1392" baseLine="1319" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="700" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="-40">
                            <wd l="7234" t="1171" r="7334" b="1392">ARMARMRM</wd>
                        </ln>
                    </para>
                </dd>
                <dd l="6859" t="1114" r="7020" b="1426">
                    <para l="6888" t="1118" r="6989" b="1426" alignment="left" spaceBefore="29" spaceAfter="23" lsp="exactly" lspExact="101" language="en">
                        <ln l="6888" t="1118" r="6989" b="1426" baseLine="1307" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="700" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="-31">
                            <wd l="6888" t="1118" r="6989" b="1426">RM</wd>
                        </ln>
                    </para>
                </dd>
            </dd>
        </body>
    </page>
</document>
```

I have tried using `contains` and ensuring that the value is NaN. I've also researched about using `matches` and have had a look at regex, though this is apparently only available in a XSLT 2.

Is there actually a way to do this in XSLT? If so, how?

**Clarification**
When I say
*Note that the structure and values of other nodes are not permanent* I mean that you cannot use an Xpath to navigate to a node, since that Xpath can change.

Comment: You need to select the string or you need to select the element that contains that string?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by, "Note that the structure and values of other nodes are not permanent." You need to be more clear about that.

Comment: What does *"select a string with an exact value of "RM""* mean? I see there is a `<wd>` element with the *text value* of "RM" in your document. Is that what you refer to? If so, what do you expect to see as the result?

Comment: @lwburk I need to select the string itself
@michael.hor257k That is what I refer to, yes. I simply want to select that value and print it using `<xsl:value-of select=""/>`

Comment: To answer this literally: you could use `<xsl:value-of select="'RM'"/>`

Comment: "I simply want to select that value and print it" - there's nothing to "select", if the value is hard-coded you can just use `<xsl:text>RM</xsl:text>`

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks, that was it! *kicking myself*

Comment: Wow. I was going to suggest something similar, but felt like I *must* be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The following selects the string that contains *only* the letters "RM":

```
//ss:wd[. = 'RM']
```